# How to customize terminal palette

Tags: settings, pantheon-terminal, themes

In Elementary OS 5.1 Hera the native terminal has three "profiles" (is it really profiles?): *Dark*, *High Contrast*, *Solarized Light*. Ideally I would like to add a new profile "Nord" which uses the [nord palette](https://github.com/arcticicestudio/nord) or if it's not possible to change only the *Dark* profile accordingly. Is it possible? If so how to achieve it properly?

UPDATE: So far I was able to change palette via *dconf Editor* by setting it to `#3b4252:#bf616a:#a3be8c:#ebcb8b:#81a1c1:#b48ead:#88c0d0:#e5e9f0:#4c566a:#bf616a:#a3be8c:#ebcb8b:#81a1c1:#b48ead:#8fbcbb:#eceff4`

I also changed foreground/background to `#d8dee9` and `rgba(46,52,64,0.95)` respectively.
The problem with the approach is as soon as I switch from *Dark* to *Solirized Light* and go back to *Dark* my custom defined foreground/background colors return to defaults. So the question is: Is it possible to preserve my custom defined colors for *Dark* mode?

Comment: Seems like you've already found the actual answer, but something to note here is that the Elementary developers decided to purposefully restrict the color choices in Terminal three palette sets so anything you do outside of that is going to be at risk of conflicting with the defaults.

If you need finer grained control you can install Gnome Terminal instead, but again that's kind of coloring outside the lines as Elementary is designed to be an "Omakase" experience :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd commented on this but I'm actually going to answer. It's not possible to preserve your custom palette changes made with dconf editor when switching themes that I'm aware of.

Comment: Yes, changes in dconf are temporary. But maybe just maybe there are some *other* config files that I can edit and setup my own defaults for *Dark* profile? Something like `gtk.css` for customizing wingpanel manually.

Answer (score 1):

You Can change two ways:

1. System-wide by editing `gtk-dark.css` only.
2. Or only changing color palette for `terminal` only by editing below file:

   /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/io.elementary.terminal.gschema.xml

Here is the results either way
 [image]